# Confused by (drive-by?) downvoting - please help me improve my question style (if applicable)

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I'm confused by a recent downvote. (I'd shrug it off, but I have noticed similar downvotes to -- IMHO, of course -- completely regular technical questions.)

Can someone shed some light on why [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14195327/321013) might be downvoted (other than random)?

(It was downvoted as it [currently](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14195327/3) stands.)

Comment: We really can't know. Might be "voting troll", might be decent user who honestly thought something is lacking or wrong in your post. Worth to mention the downvote occured at January 15th in 00:37, while the answer was edited 10 minutes before that. This means the edit caused the question to be bumped back to the front page and somebody noticed it there. By the way, you can see upvotes/downvotes of question and its answer in the [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14195327/timeline). :)

Comment: I just want to say thanks for coming here and inviting constructive criticism on your question, rather than taking the votes personally.

Comment: @BradLarson Isn't that the whole point behind people wanting a reason as a requirement for downvotes.  We want to be able to improve on what we've done wrong but if all we get is a downvote and no comment then it's like someone leaving a "you suck" sign/etc on your door and you not knowing why.  It doesn't improve the community to have downvotes with no reason/explanation.

Comment: I am with @Myzifer, it would sure help to know why the downvote, so that I could improve a question, or an answer (like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65298483/how-to-tell-if-a-regex-match-is-on-the-same-line-or-before-or-after/65299363#65299363).

How about this spec change / feature enhancement? When you click on a downvote icon, you have to enter a mandatory explanation > 20 chars, which will show up as a comment. If anonymity is desired, you could check a box "post feedback as anonymous coward"

Comment: @PeterThoeny I support this feature addition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer cleanup from comment:

We really can't know. Might be "voting troll", might be decent user who honestly thought something is lacking or wrong in your post. Worth to mention the downvote occured at January 15th in 00:37, while the answer was edited 10 minutes before that. This means the edit caused the question to be bumped back to the front page and somebody noticed it there. By the way, you can see upvotes/downvotes of question and its answer in the timeline. :) – Sha Wiz Dow Ard Jan 21 at 8:58